# StructLayout doesn't work when passing structs with strings to unmanaged code in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I am trying to make a chess interface using Unity. I have built a simple chess engine in c++ and decided to use its move generation function to verify moves in Unity. So I compiled it as a DLL and I'm using P/Invoke to call it.

What I'm trying to do is to get the moves (strings) inside the struct's array member.

The relevant code below worked in another project (on .Net 5.0), but it doesn't work within Unity. The error I'm getting is:

MarshalDirectiveException: Type string which is passed to unmanaged code must have a StructLayout attribute. DLLTEST.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/DLLTEST.cs:21)

And this confuses me, as it definitely DOES have a StructLayout attribute, doesn't it? What am I missing here?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class DLLTEST : MonoBehaviour
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct MOVES_IMPORT
    {
        int size;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 218)]
        public string[] Array;
    };

    [DllImport("LittleChessEngine.dll")]
    static extern int EXP_LEGAL_MOVES(ref MOVES_IMPORT mvs);

    void Start()
    {
        var mvs = new MOVES_IMPORT();
        var size = EXP_LEGAL_MOVES(ref mvs);
    }
}
```

if relevant:

c++ struct:

```
struct MOVES_EXPORT {
    int size = 0;
    char* array[218];
};
```

function signature in c++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int EXP_LEGAL_MOVES(MOVES_EXPORT *moves_exp)
```

This specific solution I took from

https://gist.github.com/esskar/3779066

Also, please don't mind the fixed 218 array size or the naming inconsistencies, that's not what I'm here for!

Any ideas are appreciated!

Edit1: added extern "C" and changed the name of the function in C# so it matches that of the C++ function

Comment: What happens if you move `MOVES_IMPORT` out of `DLLTEST` so it isn't a [nested type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types)?

Comment: I just tried it. It behaves exactly the same. @dbc

Comment: Given entry point has mangled name, it migth be worth to try to declare c++ function as `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)`, so to be c method instead of c++ one, same way as in the mentioned Gist

Comment: It seems to behave the same, even with that. I get the same exception. @Renat

Comment: *Also, please don't mind the fixed 218 array size or the naming inconsistencies, that's not what I'm here for!* -- but just out of curiosity, does the problem still occur with a simpler struct consisting only of a single integer?

Comment: It does work with simpler structs. I tried now with a struct consisting of 2 integers. It doesn't even need to be specified a StructLayout. So the problem seems to be the string array itself, then? I think I should add that using the fixed size array was the only way that I could get this to work. Previous attempts have been with a char**, but I couldn't figure out how to unmarshal it. I'm pretty new to this stuff. @dbc

Comment: @bogdane - I'd start by taking a look at the Mono doc page [Interop with Native Libraries](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#strings).  It has several examples of marshalling strings as well as marshalling [arrays embedded in structures](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#arrays-embedded-within-structures).  Honestly a fixed-size array of 218 pointers may be hard to marshal.  Can you change the definition of your C++ struct?

Comment: You need the right calling convention `[DllImport("LittleChessEngine.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.CDecl)]` "I have built a simple chess engine in c++" why didn't you just do it all in C#?

Comment: Thank you for the resource! I'll read it and try yo make it work. I can change the C++ definition of the struct. I'll update on this later. @dbc

Comment: I hadn't planned all of this. But I am more experienced with C++ than with C#, and I also wanted a break from all the OOP I did in school. The code is a bit messy and all, but I figured it would be fine, since my engine was always going to be very straight forward and relatively compact. And now I get to learn about dealing with unmanaged memory in C#, which is kind of interesting. Also, adding the calling convention didn't make it work, sadly. @Charlieface

Comment: Try `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.ByValStr, SizeConst = 218)] public string[] Array;`

Comment: Thank you, guys! I read the Mono Doc page @dbc pointed me to and I figured it out.